# Deploying ERC 725 (Blockchain Identity IDs) on Quorum?

Tags: quorum, identity

I refer to ERC 725 -- Blockchain for Identity. From a smart contract code angle, it looks to be just another smart contract that I deploy onto the blockchain.

Am wondering if Quorum can be used to deploy blockchain identity at scale?

References:
https://github.com/ethereum/EIPs/blob/master/EIPS/eip-725.md

Answer (score 0):

No reason why it wouldn't work with Quorum out of the box.